# Isolation of parameter values of neural network

Tags: information-theory, machine-learning, neural-networks, statistical-mechanics, system-identification

In Section 1 of [Structural identifiability of generalized constraint neural network models for nonlinear regression](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925231207003967) by Yang et al, the authors have defined **structural identifiability** on the second page as follows.

> The structural identifiability (s.i.) is concerned with the uniqueness
>   of the parameters determined from the in- put–output data. The term
>   ‘structural’ means independent of the parameter values [12]. If
>   different parameter values lead to different output throughout the
>   parameter space, the model is said to be structurally global
>   identifiable (s.g.i.); if all different parameter values that lead to
>   identical output are isolated from each other, the model is
>   structurally local identifiable (s.l.i.), otherwise, it is
>   structurally nonidentifiable (s.n.i.).

**My question:**
What does it mean when the authors say

> all different parameter values that lead to identical output are
>   **isolated** from each other
>   ?

Comment: I would guess that it's saying that for any given output, the set of parameter values that lead to that output form a discrete set.  That is, no such parameter value is the limit of a sequence of other such parameter values.

Comment: @RobertIsrael You have a model - say a probility distribution- $f_\theta(x)$. It is very possible that for two different parameters $\theta_1,\theta_2$ you get $\forall x, f_{\theta_1}(x) = f_{\theta_2}(x)$. But an even worse case is when you have a smooth curve $\theta(t)$ in the space of parameters such that $\forall t,  \forall x, f_{\theta(t)}(x) = f_{\theta(0)}(x)$, in that latter case the model is said nonidentifiable.

Comment: Also recall that in general you have a dataset $x_i$ and a given or estimated probability distribution $\tilde{f}(x_i)$ over it, and you want to find $\theta$ such that $f_\theta(x)$ approximates $\tilde{f}(x_i)$ as good as possible. So identifiability is about the uniqueness of that $\theta$.

Comment: @user1952009 And even if it's not smooth.  Of course, in typical applications it's rare to find curves that are not piecewise smooth.